# How to optimise large loops for debug mode

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, optimization, sfml

I have implemented a pixel mask class used for checking for perfect collision. I am using SFML so the implementation is fairly straight forward:

Loop through each pixel of the image and decide whether its true or false based on its transparency value. Here is the code I have used:

```
// Create an Image from the given texture
    sf::Image image(texture.copyToImage());

    // measure the time this function takes
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time time = sf::Time::Zero;
    clock.restart();

    // Reserve memory for the pixelMask vector to avoid repeating allocation
    pixelMask.reserve(image.getSize().x);

    // Loop through every pixel of the texture
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < image.getSize().x; i++)
    {
        // Create the mask for one line
        std::vector<bool> tempMask;
        // Reserve memory for the pixelMask vector to avoid repeating allocation
        tempMask.reserve(image.getSize().y);

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < image.getSize().y; j++)
        {
            // If the pixel is not transparent
            if (image.getPixel(i, j).a > 0)
                // Some part of the texture is there --> push back true
                tempMask.push_back(true);
            else
                // The user can't see this part of the texture --> push back false
                tempMask.push_back(false);
        }
        pixelMask.push_back(tempMask);
    }

    time = clock.restart();
    std::cout << std::endl << "The creation of the pixel mask took: " << time.asMicroseconds() << " microseconds (" << time.asSeconds() << ")";
```

I have used the an instance of the `sf::Clock` to meassure time.

My problem is that this function takes ages (e.g. 15 seconds) for larger images(e.g. 1280x720). Interestingly, **only in debug mode**. When compiling the release version the same texture/image only takes 0.1 seconds or less.

I have tried to reduce memory allocations by using the resize() method but it didn't change much. I know that looping through almost 1 million pixels is slow but it should not be 15 seconds slow should it?

Since I want to test my code in debug mode (for obvious reasons) and I don't want  to wait 5 min till all the pixel masks have been created, what I am looking for is basically a way to:

- Either optimise the code / have I missed somthing obvious?
- Or get something similar to the release performance in debug mode

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Debug mode are always SLOW; do not optimize for that.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  If it's Visual Studio, just change your release settings to generate debug information.  In addition, turn off the optimizations for release mode.  A **lot** of the slowness for VS is due to iterator checking -- take that away and even an unoptimized, release program runs significantly faster.

Comment: Instead of a *vector of vectors* you could use a single vector. That will save a lot of allocations (which are usually very slow). Then access the `x` `y` values using a math formula `mask[(x * width) + y]`

Comment: Also *pixel* by *pixel* checking for collisions may be a lot slower than checking the general shapes that the game entities occupy

Comment: If you have c++ compiler with c++11 support, use it, call `pixelMask.push_back(move(tempMask));` you can move this object instead of copying.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah, Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @AdrianKoch I usually have 3 configurations.  Release, Debug, ReleaseWIthDebugInfo.  The latter is the one that is exactly the same as release, except that the generation of debug information is turned on, and optimizations are disabled.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, I'll have a look at how to make my own configuration. So from what I understand, what is causing the slowness is the iterator checking - so If I manage to turn that off I should be fine?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sry for comming back to you. I have just added _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0 to my preprocessor directives but it causes compile errors stating that the value 2 does not match the value 0 in main.obj (and yes, I have cleared the solution)

Comment: Don't change preprocessor directives.  That is a much more intrusive thing to do than just clone the Release version configuration and make the changes to the debug settings.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So how do I do that? link accepted ^^

Comment: Go to the Configuration Manager and add a new configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160448/discussion-between-adrian-koch-and-paulmckenzie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Optimizing For Debug**

Optimizing for debug builds is generally a very counter-productive idea. It could even have you optimize for debug in a way that not only makes maintaining code more difficult, but may even slow down release builds. Debug builds in general are going to be much slower to run. Even with the flattest kind of C code I write which doesn't pose much for an optimizer to do beyond reasonable register allocation and instruction selection, it's normal for the debug build to take 20 times longer to finish an operation. That's just something to accept rather than change too much.

That said, I can understand the temptation to do so at times. Sometimes you want to debug a certain part of code only for the other operations in the software to takes ages, requiring you to wait a long time before you can even get to the code you are interested in tracing through. I find in those cases that it's helpful, if you can, to separate debug mode input sizes from release mode (ex: having the debug mode only work with an input that is 1/10th of the original size). That does cause discrepancies between release and debug as a negative, but the positives sometimes outweigh the negatives from a productivity standpoint. Another strategy is to build parts of your code in release and just debug the parts you're interested in, like building a plugin in debug against a host application in release.

**Approach at Your Own Peril**

With that aside, if you really want to make your debug builds run faster and accept all the risks associated, then the main way is to just pose less work for your compiler to optimize away. That's going to be flatter code typically with more plain old data types, less function calls, and so forth.

First and foremost, you might be spending a lot of time on debug mode assertions for safety. See things like checked iterators and how to disable them:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx

For your case, you can easily flatten your nested loop into a single loop. There's no need to create these pixel masks with separate containers per scanline, since you can always get at your scanline data with some basic arithmetic (`y*image_width` or `y*image_stride`). So initially I'd flatten the loop. That might even help modestly for release mode. I don't know the SFML API so I'll illustrate with pseudocode.

```
const int num_pixels = image.w * image.h;
vector<bool> pixelMask(num_pixels);
for (int j=0; j < num_pixels; ++j)
    pixelMask[j] = image.pixelAlpha(j) > 0;
```

Just that already might help a lot. Hopefully SFML lets you access pixels with a single index without having to specify column and row (`x` and `y`). If you want to go even further, it might help to grab the pointer to the array of pixels from SFML (also hopefully possible) and use that:

```
vector<bool> pixelMask(image.w * image.h);

const unsigned int* pixels = image.getPixels();
for (int j=0; j < num_pixels; ++j)
{
    // Assuming 32-bit pixels (should probably use uint32_t).
    // Note that no right shift is necessary when you just want 
    // to check for non-zero values.
    const unsigned int alpha = pixels[j] & 0xff000000;
    pixelMask[j] = alpha > 0;
}
```

Also `vector<bool>` stores each boolean as a single bit. That saves memory but translates to some more instructions for random-access. Sometimes you can get a speed up even in release by just using more memory. I'd test both release and debug and time carefully, but you can try this:

```
vector<char> pixelMask(image.w * image.h);

const unsigned int* pixels = image.getPixels();
char* pixelUsed = &pixelMask[0];
for (int j=0; j < num_pixels; ++j)
{
    const unsigned int alpha = pixels[j] & 0xff000000;
    pixelUsed[j] = alpha > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loops are faster if working with costants:
1. for (unsigned int i = 0; i < image.getSize().x; i++) get this image.getSize() before the loop. 
2. get the mask for one line out of the loop and reuse it. Lines are of the same length I assume.      std::vector tempMask;
This shall speed you up a bit.
Note that the compilation for debugging gives way more different machine code.